# Gulp dest() dynamic destination folders based on file names

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, directory, gulp

I want to iterate over all the src files and move every file in a folder named with the file name itself, for example.

from:

```
hello.js
omg.js
```

to:

```
hello/
  hello.js
omg/
  omg.js
```

I have this task:

```
gulp.src('/*.js')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/' + filename here.......));
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gulp.task('pack', function () {
  return gulp.src('temp/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname += "/"+path.basename;
        path.extname = ".min.js";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Comment: This code will move the files and also rename it to .min.js if you do not want that functionality then you can skip that pipe which is renaming it.

Comment: Man i am trying to set a dynamic destination folder based on file name....i would not a fixed destination  :D