# Gulp task - include destination folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have my scss files in a folder as below:

```
-themes
--theme1.scss
--theme2.scss
--theme3,scss
```

And my gulp task below, right now the complied css files are all in one folder inside the themes folder. How can I put the complied css file inside a folder  with a different filename eg:

```
 themes/theme1.scss => /themes/theme1/style.css
```

and

```
themes/theme2.scss => /themes/theme2/style.css
```

Is this possible?

```js
gulp.task('sass-theme', function () {
 return gulp.src('./assets/sass/themes/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({
   outputStyle: 'expanded',
  }))
  .on('error', sass.logError)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/themes'))
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp dest() dynamic destination folders based on file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025871/gulp-dest-dynamic-destination-folders-based-on-file-names)

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try...